# Hidden Characters in String ruining SQL statement (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I have a variable which I am appending to an SQL statement, but there seem to be hidden characters that are causing errors.

I have the  $addToInventory variable that is a number (e.g. 405,000).
I'm trying the following snippet of code to rid myself of the characters but when I echo I still see \0\0\0\0 (null) after the number.

```
$addToInventory= str_replace(",", "", $pieces[1]);
$addToInventory= str_replace("\r", "", $addToInventory);    
$addToInventory= str_replace("\n", "",$addToInventory); 
$addToInventory = preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u', '', mysql_real_escape_string($addToInventory));
$sql_query = "UPDATE products set products_quantity = " .$addToInventory."  where products_model like '$code'";
```

Echoing the $sql_query produces:

```
UPDATE products set products_quantity = 405000\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 where products_model like '111'.
```

Comment: What particular errors?

Comment: The sql statement does not run. When viewing the SQL in the browser it initially looks correct but because the actual PHP string contains NUL characters it fails. Copying and pasting the SQL statement from the HTML generated in the browser works fine.

Comment: What is particular error mysql throws?

Comment: Give me a second to check... up to know I was checking the boolean returned by executing the query. John Conde answer did the trick though.

Comment: Also I see no point in using LIKE here

Comment: True, no wildcards so = is fine. I can't get PHP to output the specific error. The only indication is that the updated values do not appear,and the sql execution call returns false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). It removes NUL-bytecharacters.

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the
>   beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will
>   strip these characters:
>
> - " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
> - "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
> - "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
> - "\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
> - "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
> - "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

```
$addToInventory= str_replace(",", "", $pieces[1]);
$addToInventory= trim($addToInventory);
```

Comment: Thanks..this did just the trick. Didn't know that specific function :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of all white-space characters surrounding a string, use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.trim.php).

```
$addToInventory = trim( $addToInventory );
```

<sub>Your current code seems highly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Make sure to further sanitze `$addToInventory` before using it in the query or use prepared statements like provided by [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should avoid constructing queries like that, since your application will most likely be prone to SQL injections, unless you're absolutely sure that the $pieces[1] variable is sanitized. For example, if an attacker changes $pieces[1] to become "'0'; DROP DATABASE something; --", your query will become something like:
UPDATE products set products_quantity = '0'; DROP DATABASE something; -- where products_model like 'XXX'

...which will effectively ruin your database

Make sure you sanitize variables that are used to construct queries, or that you're adding them as parameters in prepared statements. Check here for more information on prepared statements:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: :) ... You will notice in the question `mysql_real_escape_string($addToInventory)`. Euxaristo - menios :)

Answer (score -1):

before inserting to database you must use some escape function n that will prevent statement mysqli_real_escape_string with trim function